# How can I fix Firebase/firestore error in React native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying to run a React Native app on an android simulator. I am using Firebase firestore.

The app works without any error with Expo. Expo uses an older version of React Native. But downgrading React Native throws an error while building the app in the device. Those are the screenshot errors:

[image]    
[image]

I've tried downgrading to `6.0.2` version of Firebase.

Here is my firebase config:

```js
import Rebase from "re-base";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "dg-vis",
  databaseURL: "XXX",
});

const base = Rebase.createClass(firebaseApp.database());

export { firebaseApp };

export default base;
```

Fetching part:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
  let id = "somesupersecretid9";

  const fetchData = async () => {
    let doc = await db
      .collection("drivers")
      .doc(id)
      .get();

    this.setState({route: doc.data()});
  };

  fetchData();

  db.collection("drivers")
    .doc(id)
    .onSnapshot(doc =>
      this.setState({route: doc.data()}, () =>
        this.decodeMap()
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: try to change in your config from `import * as firebase from "firebase";
import 'firebase/firestore'` to   `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by downgrading Firebase to version `6.0.2`. Cleaning project's cache was the solution.

Cleaning instructons:

In `/android` folder run `./graglew clean`.

Also use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project package.